# I have a question about js Async Await behavior structure

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```js
function delay(count) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(1000);
    }, count);
  });
}
async function method1() {
  let val = 0;
  console.log("one");
  val = delay(3000);
  console.log("two")
  return val;
}
method1().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Above is my example code.
First of all, I didn't use `await delay()` and this is what I intended.
First, the expected flow of writing the above code is as follows:

1. console.log("one")
2. console.log("two")
3. return val;
4. console.log(result)
5. resolve(1000);

But the reality was different. The actual execution result is as
follows.

1. console.log("one")
2. console.log("two")
3. resolve(1000)
4. return val;
5. console.log(result)

The reason I expected `return val` to be executed first is because
This is because we believed that the rest of the code would be
executed while the `delay()` function proceeded with asynchronous
communication. *However*, in reality, the `return` is not performed until `delay()` is
finished.

If I use `await delay()` Pause at `delay()`. After that `setTimeout` exits,`console.log("two")` is executed and I fully understand this concept .
However, if `await` is not used, the rest of the code is executed, but
why is the return not executed until `delay()` is finished?

Comment: It's actually `3. return val;` and `4. resolve(1000)`.

Comment: (@RokoC.Buljan this edit is slightly harder to read)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The actual execution result is as follows.
>
> ```
> 1. console.log("one")
> 2. console.log("two")
> 3. resolve(1000)
> 4. return val;
> 5. console.log(result)
> ```

No, that's not the correct execution order. Step 4 will happen *before* step 3.

Your code is executed as:

1. Call `method1`

   1. declare `val` and initialize it to 0
   2. log "one"
   3. call `delay` function

      1. create a new promise
      2. call `setTimeout` and schedule a callback function
      3. return the newly created promise from the `delay` function
   4. Assign the return value of `delay` function to `val`
   5. log "two"
   6. return `val` from `method1`
2. Call `then()` method on the promise returned by the `method1`
3. Script end

Now After some time, timer fires, resolving the promise returned by the `method1` which then invokes the callback function passed to the `then()` method.

> However, if await is not used, the rest of the code is executed, but
> why is the return not executed until delay() is finished?

`method1` returns only *after* `delay` function is finished executing. `delay` function returns a promise which is then assigned to the `val` variable. All of this happens synchronously.

Execution of the `delay` function is finished *before* the timer fires and the promise is resolved.

Comment: Oh!!!!!!! I understood.

Until now, I thought that the result of the end of the promise is contained in val.

That is, it was believed that return val; is executed after val = 1000 is executed.

But that's right. A promise is not that kind of code.

It was some box that was executed first, and the box that the value of resolve was pulled out later.

you're right. Now I remember.

thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

> This is because we believed that the rest of the code would be
> executed while the delay() function proceeded

Your code is equivalent to this. You are assigning a  promise to `val`. Since `val` is a `Promise` so you are able to use `then` and after 3000ms when it resolves, it logs the value inside `then`

```js
async function method1() {
  let val = 0;
  console.log("one");
  val = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(1000);
    }, 3000);
  });
  console.log("two")
  return val;
}
method1().then(function(result) {
  console.log('**', result);
});
```

From Comment

> As far as I know a promise is simply a piece of code that runs when a
> certain action completes.

Promises are eagerly loaded. The constructor will not return until the executor has completed. When executor obtains a result , it calls one of the function `resolve` or `reject`. So it is not *a piece of code that runs when a certain action completes*

In the below example you can see Promise is executing as soon as it is assigned to the variable

```js
async function method1() {
  let val = 0;
  console.log("one");
  val = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Inside Promise')
      resolve(1000);
    }, 3000);
  });
  console.log("two")
  return val;
}
method1()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also half understand.

that delay uses promises.

However, a concrete understanding is lacking.

As far as I know a promise is simply a piece of code that runs when a certain action completes.

But in my code no return is performed unless the promise is returned.

What's the relationship?

Comment: As I commented, something came to mind.

Maybe it's because in my code I was trying to return a value called val that the promise is executed on?

Comment: Maybe it would help to point out that `async` on `method1` here has no observable effect on the behavior.

Comment: sorry. You helped me so well, but I couldn't choose.

Thanks to the two of you, it's been so comfortable. Thank you very much.